# KendoUI grid fire update method when changing the hidden field value

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

For some reason I need to define a hidden column when using KendoUI grid:

```
    var fields = {
        ID: { type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false },
        HideID : { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: false ,hidden: true },
        Name: { type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false }
    };
    var ColumnsDefine = [
        { field: "ID", title: "ID", width: 100 },
        { field: "HideID", hidden: true },
        { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 100 }
    ];
```

I change the **HideID** column value using JavaScript (operate the dataItem) without editing the grid's record.

And the JavaScript code to change the hidden field is like below (it's inside a command-click function)

```
    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var data = this.dataItem(tr);            
        data.HideID = "123";
```

Now the problem is when I click the default update button, the background update method is not being called because I didn't make changes to any visible column. But if I modify any visible columns and click update, both the **HideID** and another field will be updated successfully in the background.

What should I do to notify the KendoUI grid that its data has been changed and fire the update method by clicking the update button?

Comment: Can you share the code which changes the `HideID` column please?

Comment: @Joe Glover Hi I add the related code  below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid `dataItem` will be a [kendo.data.ObservableObject](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject); you need to set your `HideID` property in such a way that the kendo framework sees the change, using it's [set()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#set-field-values) method:

```
var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var data = this.dataItem(tr);            
    data.set("HideID","123");
```

Once you've done that, you should find that it's `dirty` field is set to `true`. That signals to the datasource that this object has changes which need to be saved via the `update` method.

See also this article which gives a good explanation of how the observableObject can be used for binding https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#set-field-values

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! And is there anyway to mark a custom command button as edited after data.set() method?I found $(currentRow).find(".k-grid-CustomCommand span").addClass("k-dirty"); not work anymore

Comment: No worries, glad that fixed your problem. Your code snippet depends on a span inside the button which the grid may not be rendering. It will generate a span if you set the [iconClass](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.command#columns.command.iconClass), perhaps you could try setting that to a non-existent class just to get a span you can then attach the `k-dirty` class to?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that way